# how to save local file content using fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, text, fetch

I have a `text.txt` file and I want to save its content in a variable. My problem is that I can `log` the text but I can't store it in a var

```js
let fileText;
fetch("./text.txt")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => fileText = text);
    console.log(fileText);  // undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `console.log` will be executed before the `fetch` promise resolved.

If you want line-by-line syntax execution you can use `async/await`.

```
let fileText;

(async () => {
const response = await fetch("./text.txt")
const text = await response.text()
fileText = text;
console.log(fileText);
})()
```